# How do I use nohup and time together?

Tags: bash, time, mpi

I want to be able to use nohup and time together in a bash shell while running `mpiexec` such that the output (stdout), errors (stderr) and time all end up in 1 file. Here is what I am using right now:

```
nohup bash -c "time mpiexec.hydra -np 120 -f nodefile ./executable -i 1000 > results.log 2>&1"
```

However, what is happening is that time goes to a file called nohup.out and output and error goes to results.log

Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could enclose the whole command between curcly braces to redirect the whole output `{ ... ; }` such as :

```
{ nohup bash -c "time mpiexec.hydra -np 120 -f nodefile ./executable -i 1000" ; } > results.log 2>&1
```

[Gnu reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)   :
Bash provides two ways to group a list of commands to be executed as a unit. When commands are grouped, redirections may be applied to the entire command list.

`(...)` : creates a subshell
`{...}` : doesn't

EDIT :
Here not sure that it is required.
I think that the issue is that your enclosing " " is too broad.
You should redirect only the result of the `nohup` command such as :

```
 nohup "foo-cmd -bar argFooBar" > results.log 2>&1
```

So try without enclosing the redirection from the command passed to bash :

```
nohup bash -c "time mpiexec.hydra -np 120 -f nodefile ./executable -i 1000" > results.log 2>&1
```

Comment: or even `nohup bash -c '{ time mpiexec.hydra -np 120 -f nodefile ./executable -i 1000 ;}  > results.log 2>&1'`

Comment: My issue was with enclosing the redirection! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Man page for nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

> To save output to FILE, use 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'

Simple example:

```
$ nohup bash -c "time echo 'this is stdout' > results.log 2>&1" >> results.log
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
$ cat results.log
this is stdout

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

So, in your case, try this:

```sh
nohup bash -c "time mpiexec.hydra -np 120 -f nodefile ./executable -i 1000 > results.log 2>&1" >> results.log
```